# consul properties in xml configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul

I am trying to use consul for centralised configuration for spring application. When I use annotation based configuration like Example 1 it works perfectly.

```
//Example 1
@Configuration
@EnableConsulPropertySource({"root/api/defaults", "root/global/defaults"})
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Value("httpclient.pool.maxtotal")
    private int maxTotal;

    @Value("httpclient.pool.defaultmaxperroute")
    private int maxPerRoute;

    ...
}
```

However I could not find a way to use consul properties directly in xml.

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.SomeBeanToEnableConsulInXMLConfig">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>root/api/defaults</value>
            <value>root/global/defaults</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

...

<bean name="http.client" class="com.xxx.HTTPClient">
    <property name="maxTotal" value="${httpclient.pool.maxtotal}" />
    <property name="defaultMaxPerRoute" value="${httpclient.pool.defaultmaxperroute}" />
</bean>
```

Does spring has something like SomeBeanToEnableConsulInXMLConfig or any hints on implementing this class?

Comment: What is `@EnableConsulPropertySource`? Spring Cloud Consul lets you use consul for spring environment properties, but nothing in xml: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-consul.adoc#distributed-configuration-with-consul.